# Find the size of a certain code block

Tags: c, bootloader

I have an application with a BLE stack and I'd like to figure out how much space that stack uses up (more or less) in order to figure out if I have enough flash available to write an additional BLE bootloader. How would I figure out the size of a specific block of code?

Comment: Typically the size of object files or functions is printed in the map file which the linker emits, tough the specific format varies between toolchains. Of course this can be somewhat difficult to disentangle and to account for dependencies, such as C runtime functions, shared between the application and library. Probably your best bet here to get an accurate count is to measure the size a simple reference application using the stack.

Comment: per above comment. map file has it all. If you do the -ffunction-sections linker option, you can see per-function granularity. If you want to bundle them and declare everything with a named section, it will report total size for those funcs (but the latter will ruin your optimization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on tool chain, you could use some non-standard extension to allocate the protocol stack code in a specific custom segment of code. On gcc-like compilers it would be something like `__attribute__((section(".myseg")))` in the C code. Other tool chains use `#pragma` etc. You also have to change the linker script to include this custom segment.

Then finally you can simply open up the linker-generated map file (often a text file called .map) to see how much of the segment that was used.

Keep in mind that you might have to do this for flash and RAM both.